# PHP automaticly parses my string?

Tags: php, xml

Some Background info: My web application stores some XML in a Text column of the MySQL database. This XML represents a transaction for the application.

---

The problem occurs when I'm testing my library. Within PHP, I have a string:

```
$s="<flist><transaction amount=\"10\" type=\"income\">Initial Amount</transaction></flist>";
```

However, whenever I echo or consecrate this string, it turns into "Initial Amount". Am I missing a feature of PHP? How can I fix this? Wow! As I'm creating this post, StackOverflow is transforming that XML into $s=Initial Amount as well... Please help... Thank-you for your time as this completely perplexes me.

Comment: In your browser, have you tried clicking on "View Source"?

Comment: it's HTML dude. It's HTML parses your tags. Go figure

Comment: I assumed surrounding it with pre tags would have prevented that, but yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't automatically parse the string.

Are you echoing it and viewing it in a browser? It's very likely that the browser skips over the unknown tags and shows what it can. You might want to considering adding in htmlspecialchars() to your output like so:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($s);
```

You should also see it correctly when viewing the web source. This is a feature of HTML to support future versions without breaking current ones.

Comment: Wow; that was it. I feel dumb... I thought surrounding it with pre tags would stop that. That was the problem. Thank-you!